# ruby on rails server command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've started to learn ruby on rails , I've got a problem with server, in the tutorial when they use "rails server" it shows port number and some other information about server, but when I use "rails server" in windows , it shows me the options of "rails" command
have any ideas where's the problem?
thanks

Comment: Are you running that command from your application root directory?

Comment: thanks , I should have done that command on the application directory to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Before start the rails server, you have to create your project

```
rails new projectname
```

and then you have to go your project's folder and try to start server

```
cd projectname/

rails server
```